# Where to get/buy the sheet music of Alla Turca Jazz By Aysedeniz (based on Fazil Say)

Tags: classical-music, jazz

I have been looking for the sheet music from this video by **AyseDeniz**.
She re-arranged it based on Fazil Say's work.

It used to be available on the Internet(Musicnotes).
But for some reason, it's currently unavailable now.
Does anyone know where I can buy this arrangement?

Thanks

Comment: is the piece related in any way to Dave Brubeck's "Blue rondo a la turk" ?

Comment: No, I don't think so...